# Decoding a payload from sensor using Python

Tags: python, mysql, mqtt, payload

I have a python script to decode the IoT sensor payloads from my MQTT Broker and insert them into the sensor data table in MYSQL DB. The issue is that I couldn't figure out how to decode it because the sensor transmit 2 payloads of each sensor at an interval.

The required information is separated into the 2 payloads. Data from both of the payloads must be used to compute in order to obtain the final data. The payload can be differentiated using the 3rd byte(either 01 or 02) which is stored in checkPacket variable.

I have included my code and decoding rubric(original payload is in Base64 format, the uplinkdata 1 and 2 in the sample picture are in HEXADECIMAL) below, thanks.

[image: Decoding rubric]

[image: MYSQL DB Sensor Data Table]

```
def on_message_current(client, userdata, message):
    #print("Message Received: "+message.payload.decode())
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    timestamp = timestamp.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    #gets payload, can converts it into hexadecimal
    payload = json.loads(message.payload.decode())
    applicationNAME = payload["applicationName"]
        
    deviceNAME = payload["deviceName"]
    deviceEUI = payload["devEUI"]
    data64 = payload["data"]
    
    dataHEX = base64.b64decode(data64).hex()
    
    #check packet length    
    if len(dataHEX) == 22:
        
        checkPacket = dataHEX[4:6]
        
        if checkPacket == "01":
            
           print(checkPacket)
           
           #slice data into variables
           battHEX = dataHEX[6:8]
           current1HEX = dataHEX[8:12]
           current2HEX = dataHEX[12:16]
           current3HEX = dataHEX[16:20]
           multiplier1HEX = dataHEX[20:22]
           #convert HEX to decimal and store the value 
           battDEC = int(battHEX, 16)
           battVoltage = battDEC / 10      
           #convert current HEX to DEC     
           current1DEC = int(current1HEX, 16)
           current2DEC = int(current2HEX, 16)
           current3DEC = int(current3HEX, 16)
                
           multiplier_1 = int(multiplier1HEX, 16)
           #Final phase 1 current value
           current_1 = (current1DEC * multiplier_1)/1000

        
#         current_sum = current_1 + current_2 + current_3


           print("Device EUI: ", deviceEUI)
           print("Timestamp: ", timestamp)
           print("Base64: ", data64)
           print("Hexadecimal: ", dataHEX)
           print("Current 1: ", current1HEX, "(HEX) ->", current1DEC, "(DEC) ->", current_1, "(Ampere)")
           #print("Current 2: ", current2HEX, "(HEX) ->", current2DEC, "(DEC) ->", current_2, "(Ampere)")
           #print("Current 3: ", current3HEX, "(HEX) ->", current3DEC, "(DEC) ->", current_3, "(Ampere)")
           print("Battery Voltage: ", battVoltage, "(Volt)")
            
            
           output = {"Device EUI": deviceEUI,
#                       "Device Name": deviceNAME,
                      "Timestamp": timestamp,                     
#                       "Battery Level": battVoltage,
                      "Current 1": current_1}
#                       "Current 2": current_2,
#                       "Current 3": current_3,}
#                       "Current sum": current_sum}

           #sql command to insert
           command = "INSERT INTO `Current Data` (`Device EUI`, `Timestamp`,\
                      `Current`)\
                      VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"\
                      

           cursor.execute(command, (output["Device EUI"],
                                     output["Timestamp"],
                                     output["Current 1"]))
           sql.commit()
           
        
        elif checkPacket == "02":
            
            print(checkPacket)
            #slice data into variables
            multiplier2HEX = dataHEX[8:10]
            multiplier3HEX = dataHEX[10:12]
            #convert current HEX to DEC 
            multiplier_2 = int(multiplier2HEX, 16)   
            multiplier_3 = int(multiplier3HEX, 16)
            #final phase 2 and 3 current computation
            current_2 = (current2DEC * multiplier_2)/1000
            current_3 = (current3DEC * multiplier_3)/1000
    
    else:
        print(dataHEX, "Invalid length of bytes")
        
    
client = mqtt.Client()

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_log = on_log

client.connect(broker_url, broker_port)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `Current Sensors`")
results = cursor.fetchall()

#for loop to subcribe to all topics according to the serial    
for i in range(len(results)):
    results[i] = list(results[i])
    topics_current = "application/6/device/" + str(results[i][0]) + "/rx"
    client.subscribe(topics_current, 1)
    client.message_callback_add(topics_current, on_message_current)

client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly the is question here? Is it how do you deal with it being 2 separate messages? If so what approaches have you already considered?

Comment: Your code example doesn't use any fields from the "other" packet, so not seeing where you actually need both packets.  Also, what order do they come in?  How are you pairing them up?  Normally you would have some kind of flag var that would be set when #1 comes in, and checked when #2 comes in to see if you have enough data to do your DB write.